# The animation suddenly disappear for all my pages on iOS7, very random and hard to reproduce

Tags: animation, ios7

The animation suddenly disappear for all my pages on iOS7,  it is very random and hard to reproduce ,  But once happen,  You will see all pages transitions will be very fast with no animation,  Got the following device log ": CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces."

My question is as below:

1. Does anyone experience the similar issue? And any reason to cause it?
2. Is there any method to debug such kind of issue? Since there are about 200K lines of code, How to locate root cause of the problem?

Any idea please share and thanks in advance.

Comment: Done more experiments then i got , if you do some UI operation on sub-thread, then the the above defect will occur. Is there any solution to detect which UI operation is executed on sub-thread based on the situation there are more than 200K lines of code? Any instrument tools can help?

Answer (score 1):

Answer by myself. it caused by UI operation in child thread,  myImageView.image = image;